# sending and receiving data in the same time with socket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets, oop

when client connects to server and server sends a data with `self.conn.send(data.encode())` then why can't server send another one? **I want to send data from server in any time.to do this what should i do?**

---

### server code:

```html
import socket
class soc():
     def __init__(self,s,conn, addr):

          self.s=s
          self.conn=conn
          self. addr= addr
          self.s=socket.socket()
          self.s.bind(('localhost',1234))
          
     def listen(self,click):
          self.s.listen()
          print ('listening...')
          self.conn,self. addr=self.s.accept()
          
          while True:
               data='server: '+input('server:')
               self.conn.send(data.encode())
               print('Client sent:', self.conn.recv(1024).decode())

          
soc=soc('s','conn','addr')
soc.listen('sd')
```

---

### client code:

```html
import socket


class receiver():
     def __init__(self,s):
          self.s=socket.socket()
          self.s.connect(('localhost',1234))
          print('connected')
          while True:
               print (self.s.recv(1024).decode())
               data=input('type here:')
               self.s.send(data.encode())
               
          
r=receiver('s')
```

Comment: You can use multiple threads. One thread reads data, the other sends data.

Comment: Otherwise you're alternating, so you can't send something until after you receive something.